# iOS Getting a JSON list of videos from YouTube

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I've never worked with the YouTube API before so I'm going in completely blind to the API docs... and not having much luck.

I've managed to find some sample code that can take a video id and play it in the app. This is fine.

However, I want to take a user ID (i.e. a channel ID) and get a list of the video ids (in JSON).

I'm looking at the v3 documentation...

[Here I can get the details of the channel by using the channel ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

[Here I can get a list of the playlists belonging to a channel by using the channel ID (but no videos)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

[Here I can get the details of a video but only by using the video ID. (or searching using a name, category, etc...](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

What I want to do is use the channel ID (I actually own the channel) and get a list of the videos so I can then display them in the app and the user can watch them.

... in JSON, not XML.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so two hours later I've done it :)

First I installed the iOS-GTLYouTube and SCFNetworking frameworks from Cocoapods.

Then in the app delegate...

```
#import <GTLYouTube.h>
```

Then to make the request...

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];

service.APIKey = @"my api key from google";

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];
query.playlistId = @"the playlist id I want to request";

GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;

                                       for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in playlistItems) {
                                           GTLYouTubePlaylistItemContentDetails *details = playlistItem.contentDetails;

                                           NSLog(@"PlaylistItem video ID = %@", details.videoId);
                                       }
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                   }
                               }];
```

Comment: i followed what you did, i enabled youtube api in google developers console and generated an API key, but i get this error on running: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.)".....what am i doing wrong?

Comment: solved. i removed the bundle name from google console and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you listed these endpoints:

- /v3/channels
- /v3/videos
- /v3/playlists

The solution you found is calling this endpoint for getting videos inside a playlist:

- /v3/playlistItems

Within YouTube's API explorer link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Set `part` to `contentDetails`, and `playlistId` to the YouTube playlist ID.

And here are the relevant parts of the response:

```
  {
   "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 83,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": [
    {
     "contentDetails": {
      "videoId": "kGbDymJ75PU"
     }
    },
    {
     "contentDetails": {
      "videoId": "oVPepkniuXI"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
```